# how to print ProcessID and ThreadID in dec-format with boost.log

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I use boost.log in my program, and the default formatter outputs the ProcessID and ThreadID in hex-format, anyone knows how to print them in dec-format, thanks.

this is the github of my code : https://github.com/owenliang/boost_asio, thanks.

```
  boost::log::formatter scope_formatter = boost::log::expressions::stream << "[" <<
      boost::log::expressions::format_date_time<boost::posix_time::ptime>("TimeStamp", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") <<
      "] [" << boost::log::expressions::attr<boost::log::attributes::current_process_id::value_type>("ProcessID") << 
      "-" << boost::log::expressions::attr<boost::log::attributes::current_thread_id::value_type>("ThreadID") << "] [" <<
      boost::log::expressions::attr<boost::log::trivial::severity_level>("Severity") <<
      "] " << boost::log::expressions::format_named_scope("Scope", boost::log::keywords::format = "%c[%F:%l] ", 
        boost::log::keywords::depth = 1) << boost::log::expressions::smessage;
```

Answer (score 6):

Boost Log provides the thread and process IDs as class type. If you want to get their integral value you need to get their native ID first as follows:

```
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>

/* Define place holder attributes */
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(process_id, "ProcessID", attrs::current_process_id::value_type )
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(thread_id, "ThreadID", attrs::current_thread_id::value_type )

// Get Process native ID
attrs::current_process_id::value_type::native_type get_native_process_id(
        logging::value_ref<attrs::current_process_id::value_type,
        tag::process_id> const& pid)
{
    if (pid)
        return pid->native_id();
    return 0;
}

// Get Thread native ID
attrs::current_thread_id::value_type::native_type get_native_thread_id(
        logging::value_ref<attrs::current_thread_id::value_type,
        tag::thread_id> const& tid)
{
    if (tid)
        return tid->native_id();
    return 0;
}
```

Then in your set_formatter(), e.g.:

```
   sink->set_formatter
        (
         expr::stream
         << boost::phoenix::bind(&get_native_process_id, process_id.or_none()) << ":"
         << boost::phoenix::bind(&get_native_thread_id, thread_id.or_none()) << ":"
         << "[" << expr::format_date_time< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp", "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")
         << "]:*" << severity << "*:"
         << expr::smessage
        );
```

Output:

```
39157:140229314553664:[20170710 15:32:15]:*INF*:Log message
```